# How to add columns to an existing large excel file using SXSSF Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, sxssf

I am working with a large excel file ( larger than 40 Mb , more than 100k rows and 50 columns ). I am successfully reading it using POI ( 3.10.1 version ) event stream and then doing some calculation and storing result into a List.

Now I have to append this List as a column in the same file. In this part I am facing issue.

I have tried to achieve this by using the below code

```
FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToFile));
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); // Get first sheet
Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();

int i=0;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {  // Loop over each row
    Row currentRow = iterator.next();
    Cell cell = currentRow.createCell(currentRow.getLastCellNum());
    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    if(currentRow.getRowNum() == 0)
        cell.setCellValue("OUTPUT-COLUMN"); // set column header for the new column
    else {
        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i));  // list contains the output to populate in new column
        i++;
    }

}

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(pathToOutput));
workbook.write(fos);
fos.close();
```

It is working fine with smaller files But the issue is that I am getting Out of memory for the larger files. Now I tried to modify this and use SXSSF in place of XSFF to get over the memory issue (See below code). But while testing even for smaller files I am getting output file same as the input file.

```
FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToFile));
XSSFWorkbook xwb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
inputStream.close();

SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(xwb,100); 
wb.setCompressTempFiles(true);
SXSSFSheet sh = (SXSSFSheet) wb.getSheetAt(0);
Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();

int i=0;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {  // Loop over each row
    Row currentRow = iterator.next();
    Cell cell = currentRow.createCell(currentRow.getLastCellNum());
    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    if(currentRow.getRowNum() == 0)
        cell.setCellValue("OUTPUT-COLUMN"); // set column header for the new column
    else {
        cell.setCellValue(list.get(i));  // list contains the output to populate in new column
        i++;
    }

}

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(pathToOutput));
wb.write(fos);
fos.close();
```

Using a db is not suitable in my use case and i want to avoid using a temporary data structure to hold data for writing due to memory constraint.

Is there a way to write in output workbook while streaming ? Here is the code that I am using to read using POI Streaming API

```
private class ExcelData implements SheetContentsHandler {  

LinkedHashMap<Strin, String> rowMap;

    public void startRow(int rowNum) {
             
    }

    public void endRow(int rowNum) {
    // Process the row
    // Handle write to output workbook ??
    }

    public void cell(String cellReference, String formattedValue,
            XSSFComment comment) {
    // Save current row in rowMap ( column name => cell value )
    }

    public void headerFooter(String text, boolean isHeader, String tagName) 
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: At first: How are you writing the workbooks? There is no code doing this in your code samples. But the `SXSSF` approach is a dead end. `SXSSF` is for adding new rows only. You cannot edit all existing rows with `SXSSF` as these rows are no longer in random access memory. This is how `SXSSF` saves memory. Qnly a portion of the rows are kept in memory at any one time. All other rows are stored in temp files and no longer in random access memory.

Comment: @AxelRichter I have added the code for writing the workbooks. 

I knew that we cannot modify existing cells using SXSSF but thought we could add a new cell at end of each row.

In this case what else can I try.

Comment: No, as said, only a portion of new created **rows** is accessible. You need to have all data in a structure outside the `SXSSF`. Maybe a database table? Then you can write them row by row to the `SXSSFSheet`. Or you read each row of data from the workbook using streaming methods and immediately write these row data, maybe changed and/or using added cell data, into a new created `SXSSFRow` of the `SXSSFSheet`.

Comment: @AxelRichter

I am already reading each row using streaming by implementing SheetContentsHandler and overriding startRow( ), cell( ) and endRow( ) . I am doing the ouput calc. in endRow() method.

I can store each row in a list or map but I am trying to avoid using a data structure to hold the entire data as it will again lead to memory issue if the file size grows further in future ( or will it be fine ? )

About "immediately writing row data" Should I open , write and close the output workbook  for each row it is being passed as event in the cell() or endRow() method ?

Comment: "avoid using a data structure to hold the entire data": That's why my suggestion to use a database. About "immediately writing row data": No, you would need two workbooks. One to read using streaming methods and one, the `SXSSFWorkbook`, to write.

Comment: Using a db is not suitable in my use case. 

"One to read using streaming methods and one, the SXSSFWorkbook, to write." Can you please outline how to write while streaming ( or link some example if possible )



`class xlUtility implements SheetContentsHandler {       
    public void startRow(int rowNum) {
                
    }
    public void endRow(int rowNum) {
  // can i write using SXSSFWorkbook here for each row as it is processed
    }

    public void cell(String cellReference, String formattedValue,
            XSSFComment comment) {
    }
}`

Comment: Updated my question. Please check.

Comment: you could iterate all the rows of the existing workbook using https://github.com/pjfanning/excel-streaming-reader and you could create a new workbook using SXSSFWorkbook and write out equivalent rows with additional cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to add column to existing workbook using POI SXSSF. It only allows addition of new rows.

The only solution is to read the existing workbook and write to a new workbook with the added column.

To achieve this we can store the rows in a data structure or database in the endrow() method and then use the persisted data to write a new workbook.